# Implementing PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver protocol in swift

Tags: swift, photosframework, swift-protocols

I'm trying to set my AssetService as changeObserver, but I get the folowing error:

`Error:(8, 14) type 'AssetService' does not conform to protocol 'PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver'`

While photoLibraryDidChange is the only required method. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import Photos

public class AssetService : PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver {

    public init() {

        // here I do some other stuff
        PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().registerChangeObserver(self)
    }

    public func photoLibraryDidChange(changeInstance: PHChange) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to extend from NSObject in order to use it in the PhotoFramework

Therefore you need also to override the init and add super.init()

```
import UIKit 
import Photos

public class AssetService : NSObject, PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver {
     public override init() {
         super.init()
         // here I do some other stuff
         PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().registerChangeObserver(self)
     }

    public func photoLibraryDidChange(changeInstance: PHChange) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        })
    }
}
```

Hope this will solve it

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 3.0 the register actually looks like this now:

```
func photoLibraryDidChange(_ changeInstance: PHChange) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

    }
}

public override init() {
    super.init()
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().register(self)
}
```

Everything else is the same in [Bart Schoon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35778234/525576)